# My product is broken by a Chrome 63-specific bug. How can I find out, or influence, whether it is patched before Chrome 64?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

In Chrome 63, when I attempt to initiate the Google OAuth2 flow in a popup spawned from an `<iframe>`, and it now, as of Chrome 63 (but not 62, or 64/65) is blocked by the same-origin policy (despite the origin being the same).

Here's the Chromium issue I found: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=796912

I don't know enough about the Chrome development process (or how the bug got fixed) to know whether this will somehow land in Chrome 63 or not.

As I contemplate how to deal with the customer impact of this, it would be useful to find out -- or better yet, to influence -- whether this will occur.

What would be the best way to do this? (Other than attempting to fix the issue myself, which is well beyond my level of skill in this area, or at least not worth the level of effort it would involve.)

Comment: Good question. Unfortunately it's a poor fit for SO, you'd have better luck on that chromium bug thread.

Comment: You seem to have been correct; my question was answered in comment 11 in the linked issue. I haven't had good luck with getting responses in the Chromium issue tracker in the past, but perhaps this issue is more widespread, or better-described, or something! Thanks.

Comment: @JaredSmith Personally I'm happy this question was asked here. I have the same problem myself, for my web app & login, and didn't find anything when googling. I've been searching for many hours. Only via this SO question did I eventually find the related Chrome bug (I never found the `bugs.chromium.org` page directly when googling).

Comment: @DavidCaldwell if you post an answer like "It's fixed now in Chrome 64 and 65", I'll upvote it :- )

Comment: @KajMagnus I'm glad you found resolution for your problem, I still think this isn't a good stack overflow question as such.

Comment: @JaredSmith yes I agree with that. Mabye it could be made more on-topic, if it was rewritten: _"Why does OpenAuth login in a popup launched from an iframe no longer work in Chrome?"_, and then the link to the bug was posted as an answer.

Comment: @KajMagnus yeah, that would meet the criteria. You have enough rep to edit, go for it. You'll want to add the actual code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JaredSmith ok :- ) Thanks for the suggestion. I feel I would edit the question a bit too much, not sure if David would like that. (Plus I'm short of time :- P). But maybe @ David if you want some getting-started-here-at-StackOverflow reputation, and you edit/rewrite and answer, I'll upvote :- )

Comment: @KajMagnus as for it being too much of an edit, I've already voted to close it for lack of an MVCE, so adding one is NBD and I can retract my close vote. So whether you add it or he does, somebody needs to and of the three of us involved I'm the least qualified since I haven't experienced the problem.

Comment: This is indeed fixed in Chrome 64 and Chrome 65, and is slated for patch in Chrome 63 (see latest comments on the linked issue).

Comment: So does somebody know if this is or will be fixed? I am using Chrome 63.0.3239.132 and it isn't (I can't close my login popup with js anymore after google login).